# How do I create a snippet using yasnippet which has a placeholder which is also a mirror?

Tags: emacs

Here is my snippet:

```
<Ignorable StartID="$1" EndID="${2:$1}">$3</Ignorable>
$0
```

what I want to it do is for EndID to mirror StartID, but after pressing tab once, giving me the chance to edit it. What happens instead is that it mirrors it, but after pressing tab once and typing, my input just gets prepended to a copy of of $1.

Is this a bug in yasnippet? I'm using 0.6.1b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug in yasnippet and/or your setup.

However, this snippet works perfectly in [recent yasnippet versions from GitHub](https://github.com/joaotavora/yasnippet)